# session mechanism in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have some questions about the mechanism of session in code igniter framework:
1. isn't it exactly like working with a cookie? because what I have seen is that all the session data is send back as a cookie to the browser. so when another request is made then all the data is sent back with the cookie session. 
2. the session data is sent back to the browser. even though it is encrypted, I can still identify all the session items, so isn't it easy to change the encrypted value of that item to an encrypt value, like changing an item called loged_in from false to true 
3. when saving session data in a database, is the session data automatically deleted? 
4. why is it written in code igniter documentation that "Session IDs can never be updated, they can only be generated when a new session is created". so when regenerating the session id in the cookie session how will we be able to compare it to the session id that is stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

1. The Session class does not utilize native PHP sessions. CI session library generates cookie when you initialize session in CodeIgniter. So actually sessions in CodeIgniter is a Cookie.
2. Setup Encryption Key on your config.php file and I'm sure that will resolve an issue you are having. Even CI session document says - "*Even if you are not using encrypted sessions, you must set an encryption key in your config file which is used to aid in preventing session data manipulation.*"
3. I personally never tried DB Session but YES CI deletes expired sessions stored in DB. CI Documentation says - "*The Session class has built-in garbage collection which clears out expired sessions*", which explains pretty much about this question.
4. CI has taken care of this situation. When regenerating session id, CI replaces old session id stored in DB with new session id. If you can take a look in to Session library; check for **sess_update()** method for more details and you can see how CI is updating new session id in DB.